# WCF Service hosted on IIS is not working

Tags: c#, json, wcf, soap

I want to build a service that exposes a basicHTTP endpoint and a webHTTP Endpoint. If i test the following project with VS2010 in running mode everything is fine; but i want to host the service in IIS (local or remotely) and the tests to pass.

Service.svc:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ContactLibrary.ContactLibraryService"%>
```

I host my web site into local IIS. When i try : http://localhost/ContactLibrary2.0/Service.svc i get :

> The type 'ContactLibrary.ContactLibraryService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

Web.config looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>    
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ContactLibraryNamespace.ContactLibraryService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="soap" contract="ContactLibraryNamespace.IContact" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" name="rest" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/ContactLibrary2.0" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>      
</configuration>
```

IContact looks like :

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IContact
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetContact/{idContact}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Contact GetContact(string idContact);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "AddContact", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string AddContact(Contact contact);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "EditContact", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        string EditContact(string idContact, Contact Contact);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "DeleteContact", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string DeleteContact(string idContact);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetAllContacts/{start}/{end}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<Contact> GetAllContacts(string start, string end);        
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your IContact interface ?

Comment: Everything looks good. But I don't see endpoint for ContactLibraryJSONService. Do you have such endpoint defined? If no, you should add it.

Comment: i didn't add one yet because i want to see this part working. I want to see that my service responses to WCFStorm.

Comment: Now there is a json endpoint and the project is still not working. any idea rohk or paramosh ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your svc file you need to associate the code behind as well as shown below:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ContactLibraryNamespace.ContactLibrarySOAPService" CodeBehind="ContactLibrarySOAPService.svc.cs" %>
```

You dont need to have seperate classes for using BasicHttpBinding and webHttpBinding.

Just change your IContact interface to the below:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IContact
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="GET", UriTemplate = "GetContact/{idContact}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Contact GetContact(string idContact);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "AddContact", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string AddContact(Contact contact);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "EditContact", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        string EditContact(string idContact, Contact Contact);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "DeleteContact", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string DeleteContact(string idContact);
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetAllContacts/{start}/{end}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<Contact> GetAllContacts(string start, string end);        
    }
```

Then change your service element in your config to :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ContactLibraryNamespace.ContactLibrarySOAPService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
         contract="ContactLibraryNamespace.IContact" />
        <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="ContactLibraryNamespace.IContact" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
         contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/ContactLibrary2.0" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
       <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="json">
          <enableWebScript />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Doing so would expose your interface IContact accessible via SOAP and REST.

The only change would be to the REST endpoint url which would be `http://localhost/virtualDirectoryname/ContactLibrarySOAPService.svc/rest/resourcename`

NOTE: Change the name of the class that implements IContact so as to make it generic rather than having the word SOAP or REST to avoid confusion.

Comment: <behavior name="json">
     <enableWebScript />          
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>        
</behavior> 

   Who is "json" ? I don't have any code behind, and i don't have any cs class under *.svc.

Comment: instead of using code behind i use a reference to my C# project. Is that a wrong/bad thing ?

Comment: i edited my question with the latest edits/errors to my project.

Comment: No that should be fine just use the classname with the namespace as the value in the code behind attribute and try

Comment: The name of the project was "ContactLibrary" but the namespace was  "ContactLibraryNamespace". My mistake.