# How can I test an .NET application based on WCF Json HTTP Post?

Tags: .net, testing, fiddler

I have written a .NET application based on WCF Http Post using Json, how can I test that? Can I use Fiddler for the purpose?

Comment: yes, you can use fiddler or browser

Comment: Browser? How can I use browser to test a POST method?

Comment: any browser can test methot `GET`, ff with plagin `Poster` can test all rest methods

Comment: I have installed Chrome Poster, can you please provide me a small guideline on how to test JSON?
Fields are :-
URL,Name,Value,content body.

I need to send a JSON for :-
    public class JsonString
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ImageData { get; set; } 
    }
}

Comment: content-type application json, and convert class into json via `DataContractJsonSerializer`

Comment: I used PostMan in chrome, and got what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/restclient) extension for the FireFox browser...

Comment: In such tools Should I use localhost/ IP for testing?

Comment: in this particular tool it doesn't matter whether you use the dns name of the server or its IP

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler's **Composer** tab to send any sort of post you'd like. See e.g. [WCF Make a POST request with a parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906931/wcf-make-a-post-request-with-a-parameters/9912045#9912045)